# find possible pair from array of string on this particular case

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I want to generate possible pairs from string array

this is what I got now:

```js
const findPossiblePair = (array) => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      results.push(`${array[i]}-${array[j]}`);
    }
  }

  return results;
};

const result = findPossiblePair(['michael', 'john', 'annie'])

console.log(result)
```

currently it generates: `["michael-john", "michael-annie", "john-annie"]`

I want it to be: `["michael-john", "john-michael", "michael-annie", "annie-michael"]`

notice `michael` becomes some sort of "anchor" because it's there in all of the elements

e.g.

if the anchor is "annie", it generates: `["annie-michael", "michael-annie", "annie-john", "john-annie"]`

I believe I need to add a parameter on the function for the anchor

but I'm in complete stuck

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the names instead and just push the pairs to the result array when the name being iterated is not the anchor:

```js
const findPossiblePair = (array, anchor) =>
  array.reduce((acc, name) => {
    if (name != anchor) {
      acc.push(`${anchor}-${name}`);
      acc.push(`${name}-${anchor}`);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])

const result = findPossiblePair(['michael', 'john', 'annie'], 'annie')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

@nick solution is great. but just for info , you can add one more line in your existing code.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      results.push(`${array[i]}-${array[j]}`);
      results.push(`${array[j]}-${array[i]}`); // add this line
      //  [...results,`${array[i]}-${array[j]}`,`${array[j]}-${array[i]}`]  //or replace with this
    }
  }
```